# Is there a way to get the datastores attached to an esxi host programatically using the vmware sdk - pyvmomi

Tags: vmware

I am trying to get the cpu, memory and disk usage details as vsphere and Esxi host level. a vsphere level, it is possible to do so by listing all the datastores and fetching their respective metrics. But, I am not able to find a way to find the datastores attached to an ESXi host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an existing script you can use: [list_datastore_info.py](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/list_datastore_info.py)

Basically, the script has you pulling the mount info from the ESXi host by way of it's [HostStorageSystem](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-6-5/topic/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vim.host.StorageSystem.html) and performing some data massaging to make it a little easier to consume.